# Search through ArrayList for same object and and merge the price value instead of adding

Tags: java, arraylist, merge

I have a subclass `BetterBasket` that can access a superclass `Basket` and also an `ArrayList<Product>`. My method `add` in `BetterBasket` is supposed to search through the `ArrayList` and if there is an object of the same type then the values must be added to the already existing object, if not the object must be added into the `ArrayList`. So far my code looks like this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean add( Product pr )
  {        
  super.add(pr);
  double x = pr.getPrice();

  for (int i=0; i < super.size(); i++) {

         if (super.get(i).equals(pr)) {
                double y = super.get(i).getPrice();
            super.get(i).setPrice(y + x);   
         }           
  }

// Collections.sort to sort ArrayList from highest to lowest product number   
(I have removed the code for this)

    return true;
    }

}
```

When I run it, the object is added to the `ArrayList` but the price is also doubled. I have tried many different variations but with no success.
Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
if (!super.contains(pr)) {
  super.add(pr);

 } else {
     for (int i=0; i < super.size(); i++) {       
         if (super.get(i).equals(pr)) {
                double y = super.get(i).getPrice();
            super.get(i).setPrice(y + x);   
         }      
  }
     }
```

Now it adds each object to the arraylist even if there is double.

Comment: How did you declare your class BetterBasket?

Comment: I'm still new to java, but if I understood what you mean: public class BetterBasket extends Basket implements Serializable

Comment: And `Basket` extends `ArrayList<Product>` presumably?

Comment: Your code following the word "EDIT" above seems ok. I think you're missing a properly defined `Product.equals()` method. Also, your code could be much shorter if you use `List.get()` instead of a 'for' loop.

Comment: Yes Basket does extend ArrayList<Product>

Answer (score 1):

What is super.add(pr) doing? I guess it's just adding the element to the ArrayList.

By adding it to the array list it's also copying the price. After that you iterate over the array list, find that just added element and add the price - which results in doubling it.

Comment: If even duplicate objects are added to the list, you may have missed to implement / override hashCode(). From your code snippet I conclude you have implemented equals(). If not, this would be needed, too, of course.

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't use hashCode(). But it *does* need equals() which is probably what's missing. And, of course, equals() and hashCode() go together, so if you define one you must also define the other (even if hashCode is not used by ArrayList).

Comment: As DodgyCodeException is writing, the equals() method needs to be implemented for the Product class. Whenever you implement equals() you should also implement hashCode (for the Product class). Many collection classes rely on that being properly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean add(final Product product) {  
    // check to see if the product already exists
    if (products.contains(product)) {
        // iterate over the existing products
        for (Product existingProduct : products) {
            // check for the matching product
            if (existingProduct.equals(product)) {
                // add value to existing product
                existingProduct.setPrice(existingProduct.getPrice() + product.getPrice());
            }
        }
    } else {
        // product doesn't already exist so add it
        products.add(product);
    }
}
```

Where `products` is the variable name for the superclass's `ArrayList<Product>` object.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did try: if (super.contains(pr)) {
         for (Product existingProduct : this) {
             if (existingProduct.equals(pr)) {
                 // add value to existing product
                 existingProduct.setPrice(existingProduct.getPrice() + pr.getPrice());
             }
         }
     } else {
         super.add(pr);
     }
 but it just adds each object individually (Sorry couldn't add it to my post at the top because it seems like i've reached character limit)

Comment: What is the name of the variable for ```ArrayList<Product>``` object in your superclass? If you use the syntax ```super.contains``` it is going to look for a method named ```contains``` in the superclass ```Basket```. The ArrayList class provides its own ```contains``` method which will check its contents to see if an object equals an object it already holds. Note: as mentioned by gufidown, you will need to override the ```hashCode``` and ```equals``` method of your ```Product``` class in order to define how one product is equal to another product.

Comment: @GeorgeAndrews I think Basket extends `ArrayList<Product>` but I've asked OP to confirm. If it does, then the OP's code makes sense.

Comment: Ahhh. Okay, that makes sense. Then it is likely an issue with the ```hashCode``` and ```equals``` for ```Product```. Be sure to override those methods or ```contains``` and ```equals``` will only check to see if it is the exact same object by identity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Product class is defined like this:

```
class Product {
    final int id;  // Primary key
    String name;
    double price;  // Should really be using BigDecimal but it's only an exercise

    public Product(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Getters and setters follow...
}
```

Then you need to write an equals() method:

```
class Product {
    final int id;  // Primary key
    String name;
    double price;  // Should really be using BigDecimal but it's only an exercise

    @Override
    publc boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceOf Product))
            return false;
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        return id == o.id;
    }

    @Override
    publc int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    // The rest...
}
```

Then your existing code should work (it relied on what I suspect was a missing equals method) but you can shorten it to this:

```
@Override
public boolean add(Product pr) {
    int index = indexOf(pr);
    if (index >= 0) {
        Product existingProduct = get(index);
        existingProduct.setPrice(existingProduct.getPrice() + pr.getPrice());
    } else {
        add(pr);
    }
    return true;
}
```

By the way, a couple more suggestions:

1. Don't derive your Basket class from `ArrayList<Product>`. Instead, hold your list in a `private final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();`. Your Basket is not really an ArrayList. If it was, it would mean you could pass a basket to *any* miscellaneous method that takes an ArrayList. Your Basket is implemented *in terms of* an ArrayList. Do a search with the term "prefer composition to inheritance" for more details.
2. Since you can't have multiple instances of the same product in your basket, you really should be using a HashSet instead of an ArrayList.
3. Instead of `existingProduct.setPrice(existingProduct.getPrice() + pr.getPrice());` you should define a method Product.adjustPrice and call `existingProduct.adjustPrice(pr.getPrice());`. Search "tell, don't ask principle".
4. In more advanced applications – if there is a possibility of adjusting the price of a product from multiple threads – you will need to apply synchronization. I doubt you'll need to go that far at this stage, but just mentioning this for the future.